# Mobilenumber validation in Regular Expression which allows + at beginning only

Tags: regex

```
var inputValue='+98765+'
inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^+0-9]/g, '');
```

By using the above regular expression I restrict my input to be 0-9 or +.

But I need to restrict the '+' symbol only at beginning not in the middle or end of the string.

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: When asking for help with `replace`, a desired output would be very useful.

Comment: @stribizhev : expected output is +98765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var inputValue='+98765+';
inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(?!^)\+|[^\d+]+/mg, '');
//=> +98765
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC7gN2/1)

Comment: I am not able to accept it since i am not having enough reputation points.

Comment: To accept you don't need reputation. You just need to click on tick mark on left hand of my answer and it will turn green. You will also get reps for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Having the caret (`^`) in a character class means you want to match anything that's *not* in that class.

You might want to change your regex to:

```
\+[^0-9]+
```

This matches patterns that begins with `+` and followed by non-numeric characters.

Now `+` must be at the beginning of the string you're matching.

Comment: Thanks, but for me the first character should not be removed even it is not +.

Comment: @NatarajanL please provide examples.

Comment: If i enter the string as 1234567890+xyx then +xyz should be removed. If i enter 12345367 nothing should be removed.

Comment: @NatarajanL then why not `[^0-9]`?

Comment: if suppose i enter +1234567 also no characters should be removed.

Comment: @NatarajanL the regex in my answer is what you're looking for.